# Need help running my Java .jar file from Windows batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have a Java jar file located in:

```
C:\Users\myusername\bin\MyDir\MyApp.jar
```

I also have some required properties files (needed as input arguments to the .jar file) located in the same directory as the .jar file.

I created a runme.bat file here:

```
C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\runme.bat
```

In the `runme.bat` file, this is what I have:

```
setlocal
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\"
set PATH=C:\Users\myusername\bin\MyDir\
start %JAVA_HOME%javaw -jar %PATH%MyApp.jar %PATH%propertiesfile.properties
```

However, whenever I try to run the .bat file, I get the error:

```
Windows cannot find '-jar' Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

On the command line I see Windows trying to do this:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\"javaw -jar C:\Users\myusername\bin\MyDir\MyApp.jar ...
```

I get this error when running from the command line. If I simply double-click the .bat file, a cmd window comes up and quickly disappears.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: try java instead of javaw

Comment: Do not assign quotes to your variables.  The `START` command now thinks your java home is the TITLE of the program. Use an empty set of quotes at the beginning of the start command for the TITLE. Also NEVER overwrite the system variable `PATH`!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Squashman I thought the `setlocal` just set the PATH for the one-time run for the script. Also, I tried `> start "" %JAVA_HOME%` and it gave the error `cannot find C:\Program`.

Comment: `[help-me]` You're getting there. Your second version is closer to correct. Now remember that whitespace within paths requires quotes in Windows: `> start "" "%JAVA_HOME%javaw"` .

Comment: @Arkadiy I tried that: `> start "" "%JAVA_HOME%javaw" -jar %PATH%MyApp.jar` but absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: That likely means your app is just exiting w/o creating any windows. Try plain "java" rather than javaw.

Comment: @Brian technically you are correct but if your batch file has to use any other program that was originally in your path you will now have to specify the full path to the program. Best Practice is too just never overwrite the path variable.

Comment: @Squashman Ok ... I'll start using "custom" names like `MY_JAVA_HOME`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Double quotes around the set command, not inside the variables.

Also, I see no reason to use the START command unless you want to do more in your batch file in the original command prompt after starting your Java in a second command prompt.  Possible but seems unlikely.

Generally, you will just type in the executable or use CALL so that the executable runs and control returns to the batch after reaching conclusion.

Additionally, you changed your system path variable to be just the path of your java files which will make the session pretty screwy.  Thankfully this should only persist in your open command windows and those spawned by the original window, so close them all and then use a different variable name for your path.

So I will put this both ways, using Call, and using start.

Here is your code using call:

```
@(
    setlocal
    ECHO ON
)

set "_Title=Runnning My Java"
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin"
set "_MyJarPath=C:\Users\%UserName%\bin\MyDir"

TITLE "%_Title%"
CD /D "%JAVA_HOME%"
CALL "%JAVA_HOME%\javaw.exe" -jar "%_MyJarPath%\MyApp.jar" "%_MyJarPath%\propertiesfile.properties"

(
    ENDLOCAL
    EXIT /B 0
)
```

Here is your code using the start command:

```
@(
    SETLOCAL
    ECHO ON
)

set "_Title=Runnning My Java"
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin"
set "_MyJarPath=C:\Users\%UserName%\bin\MyDir"

start "%_Title%" /D "%JAVA_HOME%" "%JAVA_HOME%\javaw.exe" -jar "%_MyJarPath%\MyApp.jar" "%_MyJarPath%propertiesfile.properties"

(
    ENDLOCAL
    EXIT /B 0
)
```

Comment: I tried it this way, and still get the `cannot find '-jar'` error.

Comment: using the CALL method too?

Comment: I edited both to change the working directory in case you don't have Java correctly installed that would help.

Comment: Yes ... using call as well.